# Statically reference a dynamic id in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have an input text box that I want to update with a value from an onclick event that happens to another object.  In this case I know test.id0 is incorrect, and it needs to be the dynamically generated id for paymentAmountOne.  I've tried to use bindings, but that doesn't work.

```
<div id="minDueLinkDiv" class="normalLink" onclick="dijit.byId('test.id0').attr('value', '#{userInfo.minAmt}');">

<h:outputText id="minDueLink" styleClass="outputText" value="#{msg.minDue}"/></div>

<h:inputText required="true" tabindex="1" styleClass="inputText" id="paymentAmountOne" value="#{userInfo.paymentAmountOne}" style="width:115px" maxlength="15" >

  <j4j:idProxy id="paymentAmountOne_"/>

</h:inputText>
```

Any help is appreciated.

I have added the .paymentAmountOne

And this is the rendered content that is still not working.

```
<div id="minDueLinkDiv" class="normalLink" onclick="dojo.query('.paymentAmountOne').attr('value', '429.56');">

<span id="paymentAmountOne_" title="j_id_jsp_1879829640_2:paymentAmountOne"></span>

<div id="widget_j_id_jsp_1879829640_2:paymentAmountOne" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft inputText paymentAmountOne dijitTextBox" wairole="presentation" dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onMouse,onmouseleave:_onMouse,onmousedown:_onMouse" role="presentation" style="width: 115px;" widgetid="j_id_jsp_1879829640_2:paymentAmountOne" value="429.56">
```

Am i missing something?  I tried it with dijit as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your input by class. In your case:

```
<div id="minDueLinkDiv" class="normalLink" onclick="dojo.query('.paymentAmountOne').attr('value', '#{userInfo.minAmt}');">

<h:outputText id="minDueLink" styleClass="outputText" value="#{msg.minDue}"/></div>

<h:inputText required="true" tabindex="1" styleClass="inputText paymentAmountOne" id="paymentAmountOne" value="#{userInfo.paymentAmountOne}" style="width:115px" maxlength="15" >

  <j4j:idProxy id="paymentAmountOne_"/>

</h:inputText>
```

I am unsure about looking up by class in dojo, you may need to adapt that.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working.  Here is the rendered content.

Comment: Your inputText render as div which is rather weird. It should produce input tag which supports value attribute. Perhaps j4j is interfering, can you try without it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mrembisz.  I am new to JSF, and I did not realize that I could eliminate the dynamic IDs in the form by setting the form id

```
     <h:form id="paymentForm">,
```

then referencing as you suggested with the paymentForm:paymentAmountOne.

Thank you.